# Can "[getting] clean" be translated as "faire le ménage" in the context of drugs?

Tags: traduction, anglais, allemand

In English somebody who got rid of a drug addiction might informally be called "clean". I recently saw a poster translating "sauber" (in German) and "clean" (in this context) as "faire le ménage" in French and I feel like this is an incorrect translation: As far as I know, "faire le ménage" only refers to the act of ["cleaning up"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_du_m%C3%A9nage).

Comment: L'usage courant est : « *Cette personne est **clean*** », dans cette tournure, *clean* est associé à drogues et donc la personne est débarrassée de ses addictions. *Faire le ménage* est une traduction de robot dans ce contexte. https://www.deepl.com/translator donne ***propre***, mais c'est une traduction possible que dans un contexte très particulier/soutenu, en préfèrera « C'est fini maintenant, elle est ***nette*** », dans cette phrase, *clean* remplaçant *propre* sera compris par tout le monde sans ambiguïté.

Comment: Where did you see that? **Please provide a link**. You can faire le ménage regarding just about anything. And it does not mean specifically to get clean re a drug habit. However, if you get clean, you have "fait le ménage" in your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that poster, the German *sauber* actually translates to *[sobre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sobre)* in French and share with it both its etymology and meaning, i.e. someone who isn't *ivre* (drunk).

We use more *sobre* for alcohol but nothing forbids to use it for drugs too (or more likely a combination of alcohol and drugs). That would definitely not be the right word in such a poster though.

As it actually reads *faire le ménage*, the explanation can only be an incorrect (machine) translation.

We would use *clean* in spoken French too, as Personne wrote in comments.

In a poster, that might rather be a verb like *arrêter*, *sortir de la drogue/ de la dépendance*.

Comment: Oui, je n'avais pas compris que l'affiche contenait vraiment "faire le ménage". Je suis d'accord que "sobre" n'est pas la meilleure traduction car ce n'est pas ce que l'on dirait.

Comment: « Sobre : qui boit et mange avec modération. » pour les drogues en est *accro* ou son contraire *clean* en langage familier.

Comment: @jiliagre: it does really contain that text. It looks roughly like the following:
`CLEAN.
SAUBER.
FAIRE LE MENAGE.
<NAME OF CITY>`. Depictions of drugs (syringes, pills etc.) set the context.

Comment: Correctif : « pour les drogues ***o**n* est accro …

Comment: Why not telling the city? A picture of the poster would be even better...